# Change CSV from writing in one column to multiple columns

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to write items that I feed my code with a for loop into a csv.  I am able to write it to a csv however it throws everything into a single column like so...[The output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSgxg.png).  I've achieved this using this code:

```
workspace = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

with open (arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0),"wb") as csv_file:
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
for textElement in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(workspace, "TEXT_ELEMENT","elem*"):
    writer.writerow([textElement.name],)
    writer.writerow([textElement.text],)
```

The issue I have is that I want to push each new instance of "elem" into a new column.  If anyone can help me write some code to create a csv that looks like this...  [desired csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOpXu.png) I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dictionary of all of the elements (elem1, elem2, elem3) and the content.  Than I just write the dictionary into the csv rather than write each individual element and content.  I used this code:

```
dic = {}
workspace = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"path.mxd")

for textElement in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(workspace, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "elem*"):
    name = ''.join(textElement.name)
    content = ''.join(textElement.text)

    dic[str(name)] = str(content)
print dic

with open(r'test.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
     for item in dic.items():
         writer.writerow(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do:

```
writer.writerow([textElement.name,textElement.text])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this example a while back:

```
import csv

with open(newfilePath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I work in pandas a lot and this has worked great for me!